# Can I record phone conversations with my Landlord without notifying them? (UK Law)

Tags: united-kingdom, phonecall

I need to start recording phone calls with my Landlord - must I notify them before doing so? If I must notify them - could I include it in a letter that I send them, that I will record all phone conversations from here forth?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK: Is it legal to secretly audio record a meeting or a phone call? Is it possible to use such recording in court?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6934/uk-is-it-legal-to-secretly-audio-record-a-meeting-or-a-phone-call-is-it-possib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

What you cannot do with the recording though:

- Publish it (putting it on Facebook or otherwise make it available to anybody other than you)
- Sell it
- Advertise that you have it and allow others to listen to it (similar to publishing it)

But you can, with some additional documentation, use it in a court proceeding provided that you make available the recording to the other party prior to it being entered as evidence in court.

[See DMA Law: Is it illegal to record conversations?](https://www.dma-law.co.uk/is-it-illegal-to-record-conversations/)

> ### Can a private recording be submitted as evidence in court?
>
> A private recording can be submitted as evidence, but with some conditions:
>
> - A recording may be relied on in evidence if the court gives permission
> - An application for permission should be made on form C2
> - The recording should be made available to other parties before any hearing to consider its admissibility.
>
> Covert recordings of children should rarely, if ever, be admitted as evidence, according to section 13(4) of the Children and Families Act 2014.