# Is it illegal to secretly record someone without their permission in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

A woman has me house sitting for her while she is on holiday at the minute, now I had to stay 1 night in the living room as she was still here but 2 days after she left I have found a recording device for video + audio in the living room, I just want to know is there anything I can do about this? I have gotten changed in this room and to find that she has been recording me the whole time without my permission live to her phone or laptop has really frightened me and I just want to know if I went to a solicitor about this would it stand in court. She has really invaded my privacy by doing this and I'm scared incase she has cameras in every room. I hope someone can answer my question please

I just want to add, she never needed me to sleep in this room as she flew out Monday at 10pm, she told me she needed me to arrive early Sunday morning/afternoon as she flew out early Monday morning but then told me her real times when I arrived. She also offered to pay me if I came on Saturday to stay on the sofa bed and I have conversation proof. She wanted me over 2 weeks prior to her flying out to stay on this sofa bed without my knowledge and kept hassling me about have I booked flights until I pressured her on her dates and made an excuse that I was busy on the Saturday as i wasnt comfortable staying with a stranger for that long.

I visited her 2 months ago to let her feel more comfortable with me in her home and she showed me around, this camera was never there. This device only holds footage for a period of 24 hours unless it is saved and it only records once motion is activated, it is all uploaded directly to her phone through the canary app so I can't question her about this until I have money to leave but she will delete any saved footage once questioned. I took pictures of the serial/model numbers to prove she bought this specifically for the intention of spying on me knowing well that this device would be recording me in my sleep as it is equipped with night vision. She is oblivious that I know about this, I have switched it off as I am only 20 on my own in London and this is really worrying me that she could have footage of me naked and sleeping, she is also on holiday with her husband so I dont know if they're both watching it.

I've tried contacting solicitors but no one can give me a straight answer, with the added knowledge does anyone think this will work out if I take her to court? I don't have much money for it but I cant let her away with this, it has really worried my safety

Comment: @Greendrake Please don't answer in comments

Comment: @DaleM Whilst that comment may be answering the question I would not post it as an answer. Feel free to post an answer sounding similar to that comment — I won't claim plagiarism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK: Is it legal to secretly audio record a meeting or a phone call? Is it possible to use such recording in court?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6934/uk-is-it-legal-to-secretly-audio-record-a-meeting-or-a-phone-call-is-it-possib)

Comment: I was in her home 2 months ago and she never had this camera, it has been installed for me house sitting for her but she was the one made me sleep in the livingroom on the first night knowing that the device was recording me, she has also listened to private calls which I believe she is listening to between her and her husband in Turkey but I have no proof of that, the best I could do is take pictures of the barcode to prove she bought it for me coming over

Answer (score 1):

What about Article 8 of the Europe Convention on Human Rights (ECHR)? Is the UK a signatory? Granted I believe that is just a treaty, whereas the General Data Protection Regulations (GDPR) are statutes.

In most cases enforcement will be the issue here.

Comment: I added extra info if anyone is able to help more with the information provided

Comment: Yes the UK is a signatory to the ECHR which is incorporated into UK statutory law as The Human Rights Act (1998).

Comment: Article 8, along with all the other Articles, restricts or prohibits certain activities by **public authorities** not private citizens.

Answer (score 0):

### Probably not

Secret audio recording is not illegal if it is made for the recorder's personal benefit. It is illegal if it is shared with third-parties.

Similarly video recording is only illegal if it is made "for the purpose of obtaining sexual gratification" under [s67](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/67) of the Sexual Offences Act 2003.

There is no general "right to privacy" under English law.

Comment: I added extra info if anyone is able to help more with the information provided

Comment: Article 8 of the ECHR is part of UK law (via the HRA (1998)).  That grants a right to "private life".