# Is it illegal to share a voice recording, in the UK, with a third party who is mentioned in the recording if I believe it is in their best interests?

Tags: united-kingdom

I have recently left an abusive relationship and I was contacted by my ex, asking me to meet up with him in a public place at night, in order for him to pay me some of the money he owed me. I went, but recorded the conversation because he often becomes verbally abusive when we are alone.

We discussed his new relationship and I believe that it would be in his new partner's best interest to know some of the things he said. Can I share the recording with her privately under UK law without his consent?

Answer (score 0):

### [No](https://collyerbristow.com/longer-reads/the-legality-of-covert-recording/)

It’s legal for you to make the recording for your personal use - it’s a tort to share it with a third party except where permitted by law (e.g. with your lawyer or in court).

You can tell third-parties what was discussed and quote the people involved unless there is an obligation of confidence (which there isn’t) but you can’t share the recording.

> It is generally necessary to consider the purpose of any covert recording to decide its legitimacy. In a number of recent cases the courts have found in favour of permitting covert recordings to be used in evidence. The mere fact that the recording was covert does not make it inadmissible.

Comment: [Here](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/16598) is another answer that claims that secret recordings are permissible in the UK, as long as the recording is not shared. But a cursory search doesn't turn up dependable sources for this claim.